# Issue with attachments in Rails ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I'm using following code (as in Rails Guides):

```
def email(file, report_filename, report_type)
    attachments['image.jpg'] = File.read('/Users/admin/Desktop/Codica/fame_and_partners/website/maxresdefault.jpg')
    mail(
      to: 'some_email@gmail.com',
      subject: "Daily orders report #{Date.today.to_date} #{report_type}",
      layout: false
    )
  end
```

When I receive email, I have a file called `noname` with following content attached instead of my image:

```
--
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
 charset=UTF-8;
 filename=image.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=image.jpg
Content-ID: <57a9a5c241e82_b9a3fd05c463be4522b9@MacBook-Pro-citrus.local.mail>
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...
--
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.2.22. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
attachments.inline['photo.png'] = File.read('path/to/photo.png')

<%= image_tag attachments['photo.png'].url -%>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!